# Directive is not working - debug steps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging, angularjs-directive

What are steps on debugging angular directives?

I've directive in HTML and it's JS definition.

I can set breakpoint on directive definition, and script stops there on load, showing fact that directive was loaded.

I can enable logging by setting

```
app.config([ "$logProvider", function ($logProvider) {
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
});
```

Sometimes it shows useful error messages.

But all that is not enough, often directive is just not being processed at HTML at all, and no log messages appear.

How do one test that directive is actually loaded (for example, by chrome console)?

And where should one look to completly check directive processing pipeline for bugs?

Comment: chrome dev tools are good enough for me to debug directives. I first make sure directive's compile and link are called, then I set breakpoints to debug compile and link functions. I think it's better to post you directive and the problem you have so we can take a look.

Comment: @YeLiu I've already figured out problem, it was wrong 'restrict' value. I'm a bit puzzled that angular have't displayed this fact in console as error. Looks like angular does't have such kind of validation. I wonder how many other things it doesn't validate too?

Comment: There would be quite a lot of console errors if Angular put a message for every tag, attribute, class and comment for which it _didn't_ have a directive defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ng-inspector plugin for google chrome to debug.